# jQuery .serialize() not detecting select with name attribute

Tags: jquery, serialization

The following is my code to my form

```
<form role="form" id="new-category-form" method="post" onsubmit="newCategory(); return false;">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-add-new-form">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="210">Category Name</th>
            <th width="210">Parent Category</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="input_name" value="" required="" type="text">
        </td>
        <td id="select_parent_category_container">
            <select class="form-control" name="select_trans_categories" id="select_trans_categories" required="required">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my function newCategory()

```
function newCategory(){

$('#select_child_categories_container select, #select_parent_category_container select').html('');

var category_data = $("#new-category-form").serialize();
alert(category_data);

return false;

}
```

This results in showing only "input_name" and not the "select_trans_categories" value. It was working fine, but I have no clue what has caused this now.

I did google a lot on this, but no help so I am posting this.

Guys i know this is weird, but i can't figure out the problem.

Thanks, Appreciate it.

Comment: After the `.html('')` call the `select_trans_categories` select is empty

Comment: but it is just the values inside the 'select'

Comment: It works, man my bad.. such a silly error.

Comment: try closing the <form> tag